# JQuery check if SELECT value exists

Tags: jquery, select

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   if ($('select[name^="dropdown_"][value="Test 1"]').length) {
      alert("Found.");
   }
});
```

I have 6 dropdown menus on a page. I am trying to check if a certain value is selected in one of them. The above isn't doing it, although it looks right. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
$("select[name^="dropdown_"] option[value="Test 1"]:selected)
```

Though I would suggest perhaps using a class name for those option values so you can get at them more efficiently like:

```
$('.optionTest1:selected')
```

Or, at the very least apply a class name on the selects

```
$('.dropdownSelect option[value="Test 1"]:selected')
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the HTML select does not have a value attribute.. Thats's the reason you see no output..

Check This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fFWwC/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn1').on('click' , function() {
        if ($('select[name^="dropdown_"]').val() == "Test 1") {     
           alert('Found !!') ;           
        };            
    }); 
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can use the option in your selector.

```
if ($('select[name^="dropdown_"] > option[value="Test 1"]:selected').length) {
      alert("Found.");
   }
```

You can see it working here. http://jsfiddle.net/UECsS/

Answer (score 1):

You using attribute selectors in an attempt to find element properties. You'll have to check the select properties themselves.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   if ($('select[name^="dropdown_"]').is(function(){return this.value == 'Test 1'})) {
      alert("Found.");
   }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmW69/3/)